# The on-topic help page has http links

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

The [on-topic help page](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) has links to the economics and bitcoin sites that use http links.  I believe that both of these should be https links.

Links in context:

> - Questions about economics that are academic or have no bearing on personal finance ([Economics site](https://economics.stackexchange.com/))
> - Questions about accounting that are academic or have no bearing on personal finance
> - Questions about Bitcoin (or other crypto-currencies) that have no bearing on personal finance. ([Bitcoin site](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/))

I fixed the links here rather than spread incorrect links.  But still wrong on the help page.

I think that moderators can just edit that page.  I leave it up to you whether it's better to just do that or to escalate to Stack Exchange staff, possibly for a more general fix.

This seems low priority (the pages automatically redirect from http to https) but easy to fix.

Answer (score 3):

I edited all the links to HTTPS on the page. Thanks for reporting it.